# Expression Template Operators with Variadic Templates

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, expression-templates, fold-expression

Using *variadic templates* we can write a function `add`, which takes any number of input parameters, and then returns a single `Expression` (to be lazily evaluated). When called for a specific index `i`, this expression sums all elements at `i` for all the input vectors in one go.

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

template<class ... Ts>
struct Expression
{
    Expression(const Ts& ... args)
        : args(args ...) { }

    auto operator[](const size_t& i) const
    {
        return std::apply([i](const auto& ... v) { return (v[i] + ...); }, args);
    }

    const std::tuple<const Ts& ...> args;
};

template<class ... Ts>
Expression<Ts ...> add(const Ts& ... args)
{
    return Expression(args ...);
}

int main()
{
    std::array v1{ 2,5,4 }, v2{ 9,4,2 }, v3{ 4,2,8 };

    auto result = add(v1, v2, v3);
    return result[2];  // returns 14
}
```

All this seems very nice and neat, but is it possible to overload an **actual operator**, i.e. write the following:

```cpp
template<class ... Ts>
Expression<Ts ...> operator+(const Ts& ... args)
{
    return Expression(args ...);
}

int main()
{
    std::array v1{ 2,5,4 }, v2{ 9,4,2 }, v3{ 4,2,8 };

    auto result = v1 + v2 + v3; // Compiler Error
    return result[2];
}
```

Unfortunately, the second code using `v1 + v2 + v3` results in compile errors:

- VS 2019: `Fatal Error C1001, An internal error has occurred in the compiler.`
- GCC 8.3.0: `'Expression<Ts ...> operator+(const Ts& ...)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type`

Are there ways to make this work?

Comment: [Tangent] Be careful using `Expression(const Ts& ... args)
        : args(args ...) { } ... const std::tuple<const Ts& ...> args;`.  As is the constructor will accept temporaries and you'll be left with a tuple of references that are dangling.  Adding `Expression(const Ts&& ... args) = delete;` will stop that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh that's very useful to know. Thanks!

Comment: tl;dr: you can't have a variadic operator function - you have to make your `operator+` binary.